# Populating NSMutableArray from JSON

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, plist

I'm a beginner working on a presentation application that lets you pick from four different categories. Each category takes you to a UITableView which I manually populated with an NSMutableArray that looks like this:

```
slideshows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

slideshow = [[Slideshow alloc] init];
slideshow.presoTitle=@"All About Ducks";
slideshow.presoInfo=@"Preso1";
[slideshows addObject:slideshow];

slideshow = [[Slideshow alloc] init];
slideshow.presoTitle=@"The Computer Age";
slideshow.presoInfo=@"Preso2";
[slideshows addObject:slideshow];

slideshow = [[Slideshow alloc] init];
slideshow.presoTitle=@"Shovels and You";
slideshow.presoInfo=@"Preso3";
[slideshows addObject:slideshow];

slideshow = [[Slideshow alloc] init];
slideshow.presoTitle=@"Test Em Out";
slideshow.presoInfo=@"Preso4";
[slideshows addObject:slideshow];
```

I made a custom object called Slideshow with the properties presoTitle and presoInfo. slideshows is the name of the array and slideshow (lower case) represents each instance of the Slideshow object (I should diversify my name scheme, I know...)

Question is, how do I populate the slideshows array from an external file instead of writing it out manually for each category? Thank you in advance StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the slideshow information in a plist. This [link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/reading-a-plist-into-an-nsarray.html) should be helpful in that.